# Hibernate Cascade: Roles and Employees

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

First, I'll briefly talk about my issue.

I am working on a pilot project to test what I learned recently in Hibernate. The idea is to integrate Spring, Spring MVC, and Hibernate. Everything worked just fine, it seems, until I encountered this problem, which took me a whole day but still left me without a solution.

The idea is quite simple. There are two entities, a "role" and a "user". A person can have one role, which makes it a many-to-one relationship. A role can be assigned to a lot of people, which means a one-to-many relationship.

Therefore, my code is like this.Role:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
@Column(length=20,nullable=false,name="rolename",unique=true)
private String name;
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="role")
private Set<UserBean> users = new HashSet<UserBean>();
```

User:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
@ManyToOne(optional=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,unique=true)
@JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    private RoleBean role=new RoleBean();
```

Also, I used Spring MVC to bound the value. Here is the code：

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user"
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/add">
        <div>
            <form:input path="username" 
                 />
            <form:errors path="username" />
            <br>
            <form:password path="password" placeholder="password" />
            <form:errors path="password" />
            <br> <form:select path="role.name">
                <option value="clerk">clerk</option>
                <option value="salesperson">salesperson</option>
                <option value="manager">manager</option>
            </form:select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />

    </form:form>
```

You will see that in the front-end page, I added a `<form:select>` tag, under the hope that this tag will work with the "cascade" setting to do the job.

It worked just fine.

However, as I test the code further, something happened.

What I expected is that ideally, Hibernate will receive the "rolename", then create a role item using the name, and save this new role into the database. If two or more users register with the same "rolename" (which, under this setting is clerk, manager or salesman), the hibernate can understand that it's not supposed to insert the value into the "role" table again because of the `unique=true` setting.

Then something weird happened. If I register twice with two "users" using the same "rolename", hibernate gives me an error which says :

```
Duplicate entry 'clerk' for key 'UK_a5k2ae0srn5n63xyhst1dllhq'
```

Honestly, I know how this error happened. It happened because of the `"unique=true"` setting. However, if I remove this setting and get the programming running all over again, the program may automatically insert several "role" items with the same role name into  the system so that the table might look like something like this:

```
Role:
id    name
1     clerk
2     clerk
3     clerk
4     clerk
.........
```

Apparently, this is not what I wanted, because no one would expect a company/organization can have different roles with exactly the same role name.

I suppose that there must be something I did wrong in either the hibernate mapping setting, or cascade. But even though I tried hard to search for a possible answer both here and through google, I haven't found anything that solved this problem.

So, would you mind giving me a possible solution?

Comment: Can you show your tables creation script?

Comment: Look into your code when you are persisting the User...you dont need to create a new Role just assign one to the User.

Comment: OK here is the auto-generated sql statement: Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        t_roles
        (rolename, id) 
    values
        (?, ?)

Comment: I followed your advice by changing the getting rid of the "new", it still doesn't work.....Still! Many Thanks!

Comment: can you post your persistence file?

Comment: OK! Ill post now! Thanks in advance!

Comment: protected Session getSession() {

  return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

 }                                                                                            
        public T save(T record) {
  this.getSession().saveOrUpdate(record);
  return record;
 }

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of CascadeType.ALL is that the persistence will propagate (cascade) all EntityManager operations (PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH) to the relating entities.

As you don't need to create a new Role averytime you persist a User, just remove it from Role.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="role")
private Set<UserBean> users;
```

Add setter and getter. . .

Same in User.

Comment: I tried this solution before... The problem is: if I removed the "cascade", hibernate throws another exception that says something like this: "transient value ......" , which basically means that I have to persist a transient entity (which in this case is a "role")  before I save the user..... Plus, I do have the setter and getter.. ... Thanks!

Comment: Without the persistence part it's difficult to know the problem

Comment: Well... I am not sure what the "persistence part" is...?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you should change:

1. The roles should exists before the users are being created. If you want to create roles while creating the user then you will have to handle it manually in your back-end rather than depending on Hibernate.
2. Once the roles exists already, you should pass them on to the front-end while rendering the form. In the form, you should use the roles that you have added in the modelAttribute, as below (assuming `rolesList` is the modelAttribute that contains all the possible roles):

```html
<form:select path="role.id">
   <form:options items="${rolesList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
 </form:select>
```

3. By doing so, the back-end will receive a `UserBean` object with `RoleBean` set to the selected role in front-end, and Hibernate will take care of saving the `role_id`.

Comment: Thanks! This seems the right answer because I actually thought that this might be the right way. However, what I don't understand is if I should add two "modelAttributes" to the <form:form> tag? One is a "userbean" while another is the "rolebean"?

Comment: Also, can I ask how I can pass the "roles" list to the front-end in a way that Hibernate knows what each item is what when the value is returned back to the back-end?

Comment: The `itemValue` attribute defines the field that identifies the selected role in the backend. Use the primary key of the entity as `itemValue`. That should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to thank you for answering my questions and suggesting solutions!

Finally, I got this work done by following @Mubin 's suggestions.

I added some codes in the controller:

```
        ArrayList<RoleBean> rolelist = new ArrayList<RoleBean>();
        RoleBean r1 = new RoleBean();
        RoleBean r2 = new RoleBean();
        RoleBean r3 = new RoleBean();

        r1.setId(1);
        r1.setName("clerk");
        r2.setId(2);
        r2.setName("salesman");
        r3.setId(3);
        r3.setName("manager");
        rolelist.add(r1);
        rolelist.add(r2);
        rolelist.add(r3);

        view.addObject("rolelist", rolelist);
```

So, briefly I'll conclude what happened for your reference!

Firstly, my initial idea is wrong. I thought that I should pass "roles" from the front-end to back-end. However, this idea is in itself counter-logic. Companies create roles, and assign these roles to different employees. There would rarely be a scenario where employees require companies to create roles for them.

So, first, I should create roles first in the database using SQL.

After I figured this out, everything seemed smooth. If roles in the database remain constant, all I need to do is to pass info to the foreign key in the user table, associating each person with its role.

So I used this tag:

```
            <form:select path="role.id">
                <form:options items="${rolelist}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>         
            </form:select>
```

What hibernate does is this:

it takes the input from the front-end, check the "itemValue", which is user.role.id. Then compare if this value is already in the database (which is absolutely "yes"), then link the id with the user role.

I think this is pretty important because, yesterday, when I tried to solve the problem, there was an attempt where I simply removed the cascade=ALL for the rolebean, and then the program threw an exception: transient entities not saved.

This happened because without cascade, the program will simply save the "user" without saving the "role" first. If there is no "role" in the table, there is no "role id" to attach.

So, problem solved! Thank you!